# Why is this returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, undefined

So I'm trying to write a program to find all the possible permutations (orders) of letters in a word as a joke for my algebra teacher. This is what I have written from in between classes, but when I run it (in NodeJS, but it's pretty vanilla JS so platform shouldn't matter) I get

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined
```

at

```
letters.forEach(function (str) {
```

Code:

```
var name = ['w', 't', 'f', 'a', 'r', 'e', 'm', 'y', 'i', 'n', 'i', 't', 'i', 'a', 'l', 's'];
var permutations = [];

function add_letter(letter, letters) {
    var full = [];
    letters.forEach(function (str) {
        full.push(letter + str);
    });
    return full;
}

function generate_permutation(letters) {
    for (i=0; i<letters.length; i++) {
        return add_letter(letters[i], generate_permutation(letters.slice(1, letters.length)));
    }
}

permutations = generate_permutation(name);

console.log(permutations);
```

(The only reason I decided to to this in JS is I need practice in Node because I'm going to be starting a rather large project in it soon)

Thanks!

Comment: 'letters' object is null or undefined. Make sure it's valid

Comment: Note that your for loop is useless since you're returning on the first iteration. It's equivalent to `var i=0;return add_letter(...)`

Comment: `wtf are my initials` was i right, or was i right? That's what the `letters` string says

Comment: it's because at one point, there will be nothing to loop over (letters.length will be 0), and at that time it will return undefined, and that's what addletter will get, and that's the explanation

Comment: @hicurin I understand letters is undefined, I just can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

On generata_permutations you are making a recursive call to generate_permutation(letters.slice(1, letters.length)) and this is returning undefined. Since that's the second parameter to add_letter (letters) when you try to iterate letters you get the error.

Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305257/create-all-permutations-of-4-letters) where you'll find a nice implementation of a permutation. Hope it helps.

Comment: I just tried that implementation of permutation, but it uses the same letter multiple times for an output. Do you what the best way to fix this would be?